# Is there any reason the game tracks how many items each party member used?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

Is there any reason the game tracks how many items each party member used?

This [save viewer](http://rngeoff.com/SymphoniaSaveViewer/) tells me that everyone has a counter for how many times they've used any item, so it's not for the Raine title about using the ''same'' item 5 times in a battle...

Does it have a purpose?

Comment: Probably every character was coded in a similar way instead of making Raine a little different (requiring that counter) from the others. Programmers love simplicity.

Comment: @pinckerman - But it's not tracking the amount of each item used... Just that she's used one... I can see how a "Used how many items" counter would help? But it sounds like a really roundabout way of doing things. ... ... Unless something else uses the same Symphonia save engine, so it's just duplicate code...

Comment: It could be a recycled code, yes